# Create a MarkerView when user clicks on Chart

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, bar-chart, ios-charts

I have searched and searched for how to display the MarkerView when the user clicks on a bar in a bar chart using Charts (was iOS-charts) for Swift.

The documentation states the library is capable of "Highlighting values (with customizable popup-views)" using MarkerViews, but I don't know how to show one.

I want a little tool tip to display, like the image below, when the user clicks on a bar in the bar chart.

Tool tip on bar graph:
[image]

I have the chartValueSelected function ready which fires when a bar is selected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So you are using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) right?

Did you check BallonMarker.swift?

> /ChartsDemo/Classes/Components/BallonMarker.swift

**Swift**

```
let marker:BalloonMarker = BalloonMarker(color: UIColor.redColor(), font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)!, insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 7.0, left: 7.0, bottom: 7.0, right: 7.0))
marker.minimumSize = CGSizeMake(75.0, 35.0)
chartView.marker = marker
```

**Swift 3 Update**

```
let marker:BalloonMarker = BalloonMarker(color: UIColor.black, font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)!, textColor: UIColor.white, insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 7.0, left: 7.0, bottom: 7.0, right: 7.0))
marker.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 75.0, height: 35.0)
chartView.marker = marker
```

**Objective-C**

```
BalloonMarker *marker = [[BalloonMarker alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:14.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] font:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0] insets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0)];
marker.minimumSize = CGSizeMake(75.f, 35.f);
_chartView.marker = marker;
```

Comment: Yeah I have imported the BalloonMarker class into my project, but struggling with the syntax of actually creating the marker.

Comment: In my chartValueSelected function, I have created a BalloonMarker object and assigned it to the chartView.marker.

Comment: Thanks for your replies - this is very helpful.

So I've added the swift code and that creates a black bubble above the bar when it is clicked. I want to display the bar y value in the bubble as well. Should I be using the refreshContent method from BalloonMarker? Or is there a property of the marker I can assign a value to?

Comment: Okay, I changed the UIColor to be white instead of black which I think was in your original answer before red and that works fine now.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help. Yeah the colour choice was obviously just for the answer :) Btw, did you cmd-click the two classes `ChartDataEntry` and `ChartHighlight` in `BalloonMarker.swift` `refreshContent` function? They have properties you can insert and highlight like `value`, `xIndex`, `data`, `_xIndex`, `_value`, etc.

Comment: I use the same code but giving an error of Use of undeclared type BalloonMarker. Can you help me?

Comment: @tymac, how do you do this on Swift3 version?

Comment: let marker:BalloonMarker = BalloonMarker(color: UIColor.black, font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)!, textColor: UIColor.white, insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 7.0, left: 7.0, bottom: 7.0, right: 7.0))
        marker.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 75.0, height: 35.0)
        chartView.marker = marker

Comment: I am using this swift class with Objective C project. Not able to import it. I have not added the whole xcode project as I am using PODS. If anybody can help please?

Comment: @KrutikaSonawala did you ever figure out how to import it in obj c project?

Comment: @PranoyC yes, I have added files for marker i.e, balloon marker from the demo project provided explicitly the pods. imported charts to balloon marker class and called it's delegate method.

Comment: @PranoyC please refer below answer. It might help you out.

Comment: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/tree/master/ChartsDemo/Classes/Components here is the link for Ballon Marker and other markers.

Answer (score 1):

Swift chart library with Objective C code will be something like this.. I am here just showing some code snippets.

1. ChartViewController.m

   ```
   -(void)initializeChart {

       //chart specifications will go here 
       ...
       ...

       //set balloon marker to the chart
       BalloonMarker *marker = [[BalloonMarker alloc]
                        initWithColor: kColorBrown1
                        font: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]
                        textColor: UIColor.whiteColor
                        insets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(8.0, 8.0, 20.0, 8.0)];
       marker.chartView = chartView;
       marker.minimumSize = CGSizeMake(80.f, 40.f);
       chartView.marker = marker;
   }
   ```
2. BalloonMarker.swift

   ```
   import Charts

   ...

   ...

   //This method will be called when ever user clicks on a chart to refresh the marker text. You need to specify the value here.

   open override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight)

   {  
       setLabel(entry.y!)        
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Even after adding the BalloonMarker to the chart if the markers are not displayed make sure that the markers are enabled on the chart view

```
chartView.drawMarkers = true
```

highlighting is enabled on the chart data set. This is should be done after you assign the chart data set.

```
chartView.data?.highlightEnabled = true
```